# Any way to get TStringList.CommaText to not escape commas with quotes?

Tags: delphi, code-generation, escaping, tstringlist

I'm doing some work with code generation, and one of the things I need to do is create a function call where one of the parameters is a function call, like so:

```
result := Func1(x, y, Func2(a, b, c));
```

TStringList.CommaText is very useful for generating the parameter lists, but when I traverse the tree to build the outer function call, what I end up with looks like this:

```
result := Func1(x, y, "Func2(a, b, c)");
```

It's quoting the third argument because it contains commas, and that produced invalid code.  But I can't do something simplistic like StringReplace all double quotes with empty strings, because it's quite possible that a function argument could be a string with double quotes inside.  Is there any way to make it just not escape the lines that contain commas?

Comment: You could parse it with a regular expression?

Comment: ...and then I would have two problems. :P

Comment: @Remko, he's *generating* code, not parsing it. If it's common practice for you to immediately parse code you've just generated, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I believe the TStringList built in code is  "close, but no cigar".  The answer that says "write your own", is trivially easy. :-)

Comment: @Rob: Exactly.  I'm going to be parsing this code, but not until later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Build an array of "unlikely characters" : non-keyable like **†**, **‡** or even non-printable like #**129, #141, #143, #144**.
2. Verify you don't have the 1st unlikely anywhere in your `StringList.CommaText`. Or move to the next unlikely until you get one not used in your `StringList.CommaText`. (Assert that you find one)
3. Use this unlikely char as the `QuoteChar` for your StringList
4. Get `StringList.DelimitedText`. You'll get the `QuoteChar` around the function parameters like: `result := Func1(x, y, †Func2(a, b, c)†);`
5. Replace the unlikely `QuoteChar` (here **†**) by empty strings...

Comment: I can't help but "an array of unlikely characters" reminds me of "A Series of Unfortunate Events". :-)

Answer (score 8):

You could set [`QuoteChar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.QuoteChar) to be a space, and you'd merely get some extra spaces in the output, which is generally OK since generated code isn't usually expected to look pretty. String literals would be affected, though; they would have extra spaces inserted, changing the value of the string.

[Free Pascal's `TStrings` class](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tstrings.html) uses `StrictDelimiter` to control whether quoting occurs when reading the [`DelimitedText`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tstrings.delimitedtext.html) property. When it's *true*, quoting does not occur at all. Perhaps Delphi treats that property the same way.

Comment: Delphi 2010's VCL calls `AnsiQuotedStr` before adding an element to the output string.  `StrictDelimiter` doesn't affect quoting at all in Delphi.

Comment: Delphi has a StrictDelimiter property, but it works a little bit differently.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the Unicode version of AnsiExtractQuotedStr to remove the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Write your own method to export the contents of your `TStringList` to a string.

```
function MyStringListToString(const AStrings: TStrings): string;
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    Result := '';
    if AStrings.Count = 0 then
        Exit;
    Result := AStrings[0];
    for i := 1 to AStrings.Count - 1 do
        Result := Result + ',' + AStrings[i];
end;
```

Too obvious?  :-)

Alternatively, what would happen if you set `StringList.QuoteChar` to `#0` and then called `StringList.DelimitedText`?

Comment: Looks like an AV happens with `QuoteChar = #0`.  That was surprising.

Answer (score 1):

We have written a descendant class of TStringList in which reimplemented the DelimitedText property. You can copy most of the code from the original implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  LList: TStringList;
  s, LOutput: string;
begin
  LList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    LList.Add('x');
    LList.Add('y');
    LList.Add('Func2(a, b, c)');
    for s in LList do
      LOutput := LOutput + s + ', ';
    SetLength(LOutput, Length(LOutput) - 2);
    m1.AddLine('result := Func1(' + LOutput + ')');
  finally
    LList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, here's how I fixed it:

```
s := Trim(StringList.Text)
```

that's all ;-)